# Vertical centering image in unknown height div does not properly position image on mobile Safari/iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, mobile-safari

I'm using the vertical centering technique explained here on CSS-Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown

I have an image that needs to be vertically centered in a div. It seems to work just fine on every platform except mobile Safari/iOS, where the image is placed out of view. I can't seem to work out what the quirk or compliance issue is on mobile Safari that is causing this.

Here's the issue in a CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iDalc

Here's my stripped down HTML and CSS

```
<div class="headline">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a>
      <div class="background">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Durga%2C_Burdwan%2C_2011.JPG/1920px-Durga%2C_Burdwan%2C_2011.JPG">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>                

<div class="headline">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a>
      <div class="background">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Upper_Antelope_Canyon_Heart_Formation_2013.jpg/640px-Upper_Antelope_Canyon_Heart_Formation_2013.jpg">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>                

<div class="headline">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a>
      <div class="background">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Maly_Krashokholmsky_bridge_4exp_Oloneo.jpg/1920px-Maly_Krashokholmsky_bridge_4exp_Oloneo.jpg">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.headline {
    background: gray;    
    padding: 0 3.125%;
    width: 93.75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 768px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 190px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.background img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.background:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Can anyone advise what CSS issue is happening in mobile Safari? So far, I've diagnosed it may have something to do with the transform: translate-Y property. All mobile Safari testing done on device as well as iOS simulator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this in any searches, I managed to fix this on my own. Changed .background img to position: absolute; and left: 0;

I don't entirely understand what's going on but whatever it fixed it. I'd also like to add that I was mistaken in my original post. Somewhere I credited CSS Tricks for the vertical centering technique I implemented, which wasn't the actual source. I had referenced the following URL: http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center

Updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJugd

```
.headline {
    background: gray;    
    padding: 0 3.125%;
    width: 93.75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 768px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 190px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.background img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.background:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```